# Using FLAG to change an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin

I want to be able to change the default value of a navigation using a FLAG.

Basically I have two different build flavours for different markets. One has a default value view(SEARCH), but the other needs a specific navigation item as its starting view(PLU). They both have separate adapters with SEARCH being the default. I want to keep SEARCH as the default, but use PLU as the default for the second adapter/flavour.

what would be the best way to do this using a FLAG?

Comment: What do you mean by PLU ?

Comment: @JaiminModi this is just a name we are using for a product search. So we have on the app: Search, PLU and Categories as navigation items

Answer (score 0):

In your flavors set a field like this:

```
SEARCH {
        dimension "version"
        versionNameSuffix "-search"
        buildConfigField "String", 'type', '"search"'
}
PLU {
        dimension "version"
        versionNameSuffix "-plu"
        buildConfigField "String", 'type', '"plu"'
}
```

and retrieve in code in this way:

```
String type = BuildConfig.type;
```

then check if type is "search" or "plu".

Hope it helps.